# Dual touch controls turning on one axis

Tags: unity, assets

I wanted a swift look around functionality to be put in the middle of a room and just look around.
So obviously I imported the standard assets and put the FPS controller in the middle and then dragged in the Dual touch controls and build it to android.
The problem is that it only rotates horizontally and not vertically. I tried playing around with the values a bit but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have implemented the touch controls correctly? AFAIK, touch controls do not directly integrate with the mouse axis controls.

Comment: there is no need for that. the touch control prefab in the standard assets is set up to use immediately. The problem was with the target platform and the fps prefab.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what exactly is the problem with the FPS character and why it works in windows and not in android but I tested the Rigid body FPS character and it worked in android.

Comment: This answer would be better if you tried systematically changing one setting or section of code at a time until you narrow down precisely what is different about the Rigidbody FPS character that solves the issue you described.

Comment: @DMGregory I agree but working on a company project leaves no time for that. I often need quick solutions and no time for debugging further.

Comment: @Henjin Your company puts no value on long term stability and maintainability?